# Visual Studio Android Emulator Not installing profiles

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android

Hello Friendly Overflowers:

```
Os is Windows 10. Visual Studio is 2017
```

Today's problem is in getting the Visual Studio Emulator installed and running.
I downloaded from MS. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

Then I downloaded first android image into emulator. See profile below.

When i go to the main screen I download the first KitKat image available:
[image: Emulator Download of an Android Image]

I have verified:
 1) that my Hypervisor is running. (Image install Log is disputing this)
 2) my Cpu Supports Virtualization
 3) My bios Settings have Virtualization Enabled.

I have read:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx

What now?

Here is my log file from the image install on the emulator.

> 3> 2017-03-20 8:59:36 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code:
>   HypervisorNotRunning (13) 3> 2017-03-20 9:17:22 PM : [Informational]
>   Waiting to launch device... 3> 2017-03-20 9:17:22 PM : [Informational]
>   Launching Device: 10.1" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet 3> 2017-03-20
>   9:17:22 PM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments... 3>
>   2017-03-20 9:17:22 PM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is
>   already running... 3> 2017-03-20 9:17:22 PM : [Informational]
>   Preparing virtual machine... 3> 2017-03-20 9:17:30 PM : [Critical] An
>   error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 10.1" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI
>   Tablet' device. 3> 2017-03-20 9:17:30 PM : [Critical] XDE Path:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe 3>
>   2017-03-20 9:17:30 PM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android
>   /displayName "VS Emulator 10.1\" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet" /memSize
>   2048 /diagonalSize 10.1 /video "2560x1600" /vhd
>   "C:\Users\mwardell\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\10.1_KitKat_(4.4)_XHDPI_Tablet\image.vhd"
>   /name "VS Emulator 10.1-inch KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet.mwardell"
>   /noStart /silent 3> 2017-03-20 9:17:30 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code:
>   HypervisorNotRunning (13)

Here is my Hypervisor which appears to be running!

[image: Picture of running Hypervisor]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have verified: 1) that my Hypervisor is running. (Image install Log is disputing this) 2) my Cpu Supports Virtualization 3) My bios Settings have Virtualization Enabled.

The error logs tells us that your Hyper-V is not enabled, your screenshot for Hyper-V Manager can't tell us that your Hyper-V is enabled.

Please open your CMD as Administrator and input the following command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

And then **Restart Your PC**.

For more information about configure emulator for VS, please refer to [Visual Studio Android Emulator](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/).

If you're already on a virtual machine, it is not possible to start another emulator on this virtual machine.

Comment: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto changed the boot config and still did not work...

Comment: I am running straight win 10 - no emulation

Comment: hmm i did that once... Did it a again and it worked wonderfully.